# how to end a line with semicolon (;) in a csv format with excel?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

i am trying to save a file to csv format  in excel but the results appears  like this when i open it in notebook:

```
04/13/2020;20:00;8699;8745;8686;8742;5925
```

i need each line ending with a semicolon (;) like this

```
04/13/2020;20:00;8699;8745;8686;8742;5925;
```

i tried Spliting text into different columns with the Convert Text to Columns Wizard and selecting delimited to separate with semicolon , but i cannot find a way yet.

how can i convert this?,

Comment: In Notebook, do a search for carriage returns and replace with a semicolon followed by a carriage return? Or maybe (and I have not tried this) add a space in the last cell or each row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Windows/[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) :

1. Open your .csv file
2. Press CTRL+A to select all the lines
3. Press CTRL+H (Replace)
4. Select `Regular Expression` in Search Mode
5. Tap `$` (which means the end of each line) in Find what
6. Tap `;` in Replace with
7. Click Replace All

The `;` will be then interpreted as delimiter in Excel (see column8 in the image below):

[image]

Comment: ok, the problem is that the file cannot not be recognized by a data trading software. i try to import this data to get a  chart  but the problem persists . so it seems that the computer needs to read the last character ";" as a column delimiter and not as a simple character

Comment: That's what Notepad++ does when you replace `$` by `;`. The semicolon will be considered as a delimiter (see the EDIT I made to my answer). Regarding the problem with your Trading Data Software, wait for the community's help. You can also add any information (about the source/format/destination of your data) that you think can be useful. Good luck @datascale.